# Oracle SQL execution plan changes due to SYS_OP_C2C internal conversion

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm wondering why cost of this query

```
select * from address a
left join name n on n.adress_id=a.id
where a.street='01';
```

is higher than

```
select * from address a
left join name n on n.adress_id=a.id
where a.street=N'01';
```

where address table looks like this

```
ID              NUMBER
STREET          VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
POSTAL_CODE     VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
```

and name table looks like this

```
ID              NUMBER
ADDRESS_ID      NUMBER
NAME            VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
SURNAME         VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
```

These are costs returned by explain plan

Explain plan for '01'

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                      |  3591 |  1595K|    87   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS OUTER          |                      |  3591 |  1595K|    87   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL          | ADDRESS              |     3 |   207 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| NAME                 |  1157 |   436K|    47   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | NAME_HSI             |  1157 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("A"."STREET"='01')
   4 - access("N"."ADDRESS_ID"(+)="A"."ID")
```

Explain plan for N'01'

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                      |   347 |   154K|    50   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS OUTER          |                      |   347 |   154K|    50   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL          | ADDRESS              |     1 |    69 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| NAME                 |  1157 |   436K|    47   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | NAME_HSI             |  1157 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter(SYS_OP_C2C("A"."STREET")=U'01')
   4 - access("N"."ADDRESS_ID"(+)="A"."ID")
```

As you can see cost for N'01' query is lower than cost for '01'. Any idea why? N'01' needs additionally convert varchar to nvarchar so cost should be higher (SYS_OP_C2C()). The other question is why rows processed by N'01' query is lower than '01'?

[EDIT]

- Table `address` has 30 rows.
- Table `name` has 19669 rows.

Comment: can you post the number of rows on both tables?

Comment: Have you gathered statistics on the tables? The big difference here is that the optimizer guesses that 3 rows in address table satisfies `street='01'` but only 1 row satisfies `street=N'01'`. The first case the optimizer uses a cardinality estimate algorithm suitable for equality predicate, the other case the optimizer sees that a function is applied to the column in the table which means it has to  guess - probably guesses "about 5% of the row count of the table."

Comment: @KimBergHansen, I'm not SQL developer so I don't even know how to store table statistics (BTW how can I check it? Is it stored somewhere in db?).

Comment: Gathering statistics will not make any difference. The internal function will be anyway applied and the cardinality estimates for the two differently applied filters will different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SYS_OP_C2C` is an `internal function` which does an `implicit conversion` of `varchar2` to `national character set` using `TO_NCHAR` function. Thus, the filter completely changes as compared to the filter using normal comparison.

I am not sure about the reason why the number of rows are *less*, but I can guarantee it could be *more* too. Cost estimation won't be affected.

Let's try to see step-by-step in a test case.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT 'a'||LEVEL col FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL < 1000;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM t WHERE col = 'a10';

Explained.

SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1601196873

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |     5 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |     1 |     5 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("COL"='a10')

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```

So far so good. Since there is only one row with value as 'a10', optimizer estimated one row.

Let's see with the national characterset conversion.

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM t WHERE col = N'a10';

Explained.

SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1601196873

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |    10 |    50 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |    10 |    50 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(SYS_OP_C2C("COL")=U'a10')

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```

What happened here? We can see `filter(SYS_OP_C2C("COL")=U'a10')`, which means an internal function is applied and it converts the `varchar2` value to `nvarchar2`. The filter now found 10 rows.

This will also suppress any index usage, since now a function is applied on the column. We can tune it by creating a `function-based index` to avoid `full table scan`.

```
SQL> create index nchar_indx on t(to_nchar(col));

Index created.

SQL>
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM t WHERE to_nchar(col) = N'a10';

Explained.

SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1400144832

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |            |    10 |    50 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| T          |    10 |    50 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | NCHAR_INDX |     4 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access(SYS_OP_C2C("COL")=U'a10')

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

However, will this make the execution plans similar? No. i think with **two different charactersets** , the filter will not be applied alike. Thus, the difference lies.

***My research says,***

> Usually, such scenarios occur when the data coming via an application
>   is nvarchar2 type, but the table column is varchar2. Thus, Oracle
>   applies an internal function in the filter operation. My suggestion
>   is, to know your data well, so that you use similar data types during
>   design phase.

Comment: +1, Simply you can avoid this by changing the character set. Isn't it

Comment: I believe, it is better to keep the data type same. If the values to be passed are nvarchar2, then keep the column data type as nvarchar2. So that you never face a scenario of internal conversion.

Comment: @LalitKumarB, I agree with you. I just faced with this problem while I was playing with sql query performance.

Answer (score 3):

When worrying about explain plans, it matters whether there are current statistics on the tables. If the statistics do not represent the actual data reasonably well, then the optimizer will make mistakes and estimate cardinalities incorrectly.

You can check how long ago statistics were gathered by querying the data dictionary:

```
select table_name, last_analyzed
  from user_tables
 where table_name in ('ADDRESS','NAME');
```

You can gather statistics for the optimizer to use by calling `DBMS_STATS`:

```
begin
   dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'ADDRESS');
   dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'NAME');
end;
```

So perhaps after gathering statistics you will get different explain plans. Perhaps not.

The difference in your explain plans is primarily because the optimizer estimates how many rows it will find in address table differently in the two cases.

In the first case you have an equality predicate with same datatype - this is good and the optimizer can often estimate cardinality (row count) reasonably well for cases like this.

In the second case a function is applied to the column - this is often bad (unless you have function based indexes) and will force the optimizer to take a wild guess. That wild quess will be different in different versions of Oracle as the developers of the optimizer tries to improve upon it. Some versions the wild guess will simply be something like "I guess 5% of the number of rows in the table."

When comparing different datatypes, it is best to avoid implicit conversions, particularly when like this case the implicit conversion makes a function on the *column* rather than the literal. If you have cases where you get a value as datatype NVARCHAR2 and need to use it in a predicate like above, it can be a good idea to explicitly convert the value to the datatype of the column.

```
select * from address a
left join name n on n.adress_id=a.id
where a.street = CAST( N'01' AS VARCHAR2(255));
```

In this case with a literal it does not make sense, of course. Here you would just use your first query. But if it was a variable or function parameter, maybe you could have use cases for doing something like this.

Comment: As I already said, gathering statistics will not avoid internal conversion, which is the basic question of OP. The best soltion is to have correct data type.

Comment: I agree completely with your answer. But the OP also in comments demonstrated that he did not know about statistics gathering. And if he gathers statistics he might see the opposite scenario - he might see that the query without conversion estimated much smaller cardinality and then he would not really have asked this question. My point is that noone should try to make sense of explain plans if they do not have current statistics ;-) And then they should always use correct data type, as your answer clearly demonstrates what I also said - the implicit conversion gives wrong cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see the first query returns 3591 rows, the second one returns 347 rows. So Oracle needs less I/O operation that's why the cost is less.

Don't be confused with

> N'01' needs additionally convert varchar to nvarchar

Oracle does one hard parse and then uses soft parse for the same queries. So the longer your oracle works the faster it becomes.

Comment: Why these two (almost the same) queries returns different rows count?

Comment: A soft vs. hard parse will not change the cost estimation in the execution plan.

Comment: @pepuch These queries are not the same. Each of them has its own execution plan. As I said the first query extracts 3591 and the second one extracts only 347 rows. So the first one does more work that's why cost parameters are different.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I didn't tell that they would change it. I meant that it doesn't matter that oracle needs to convert varchar to nvarchar oracle does it only once: during the hard parse.

Comment: What do you mean here "So the longer you oracle works the faster it becomes."?

Comment: @realspirituals there was a typo. I meant that the longer your server oracle works the more queries it parses, hence oracle uses the soft parse more often than the hard parse and it increases the performance of the oracle server.

Comment: Oracle does not convert varchar2 to nvarchar2 at parse time here. At parse time the optimizer observes that in the first query a varchar2 is compared to a varchar2, fine. But in the second query it observes the varchar2 column is compared to a nvarchar2 literal, so the execution plan will include implicit conversion of the varchar2 column to nvarchar2 (`SYS_OP_C2C` function call) which will change how the optimizer estimates the cardinalities. At runtime the implicit conversion will happen - no matter if it is hard or soft parsed.

Comment: Not only that, Oracle does more during the hard parse than just make a notices about where and what is used. Oracle rewrites ([build a new executable version of application code](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/glossary.htm#CNCPT44480)) queries to the server during the hard parse.

Comment: Yes exactly, it builds the rewritten query that includes the function SYS_OP_C2C. The actual execution of the function (varchar2 to nvarchar2 conversion) happens every time that rewritten query is executed. So when you say it only converts varchar to nvarchar at hard parse time, that is not true. The conversion happens runtime at every execution. The hard parsing only creates the rewritten query that includes the conversion function.

Comment: I see, I expressed not clearly, thank for your comments.