# Slow with bind parameters, even slower with JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a four-column table in my Oracle 11g database implementing the extension-table anti-pattern. I noticed that some queries were taking very long and made an effort to create better indexes; it was fine in interactive session but still as slow using Spring’s `NamedJdbcTemplate`.

Consider the following routine:

```
private void getObjectIds(ObjectDomain domain, HashMap<String, List<String>> dimensionMap)
    throws SQLException {
String sql = "SELECT m2.OBJECT_ID"
    + "  FROM MetaInformations m1, MetaInformations m2\n"
    + "  WHERE m1.OBJECT_ID = m2.OBJECT_ID\n"
    + "    AND m1.OBJECT_DOMAIN = :domain AND m1.KEY = :key1 AND\n"
    + "        m1.REF_OBJ_VALUE IN (:values1)\n"
    + "    AND m2.OBJECT_DOMAIN = :domain AND m2.KEY = :key2 AND\n"
    + "        m2.REF_OBJ_VALUE IN (:values2)";
String sqlWithBind = "SELECT m2.OBJECT_ID\n"
    + "  FROM MetaInformations m1, MetaInformations m2\n"
    + "  WHERE m1.OBJECT_ID = m2.OBJECT_ID\n"
    + "    AND m1.OBJECT_DOMAIN = ? AND m1.KEY = ? AND\n"
    + "        m1.REF_OBJ_VALUE IN (?, ?, ?, ?)\n"
    + "    AND m2.OBJECT_DOMAIN = ? AND m2.KEY = ? AND\n"
    + "        m2.REF_OBJ_VALUE IN (?)";

// Prebuilding statement, no bind variables left
Stopwatch stopWatch2 = Stopwatch.createStarted();
Iterator<Entry<String, List<String>>> entries = dimensionMap.entrySet().iterator();
Entry<String, List<String>> entry1 = entries.next();
Entry<String, List<String>> entry2 = entries.next();
String prebuilt = sql.replace(":domain", "'" + domain + "'")
    .replace(":key1", "'" + entry1.getKey() + "'")
    .replace(":values1",
        entry1.getValue().stream().map(s -> "'" + s + "'").collect(Collectors.joining(", ")))
    .replace(":key2", "'" + entry2.getKey() + "'")
    .replace(":values2",
        entry2.getValue().stream().map(s -> "'" + s + "'").collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
Set<Long> rs2 = extractIdSet(getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().queryForRowSet(prebuilt, Collections.emptyMap()));
log.warn("Prebuilt took: {} ms", stopWatch2.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

// Simple JDBCTemplate with 9 bind parameters
Stopwatch stopWatch5 = Stopwatch.createStarted();
Set<Long> rs1 = extractIdSet(getJdbcTemplate().queryForRowSet(sqlWithBind,
    domain.toString(),
    entry1.getKey(),
    entry1.getValue().get(0),
    entry1.getValue().get(1),
    entry1.getValue().get(2),
    entry1.getValue().get(3),
    domain.toString(),
    entry2.getKey(),
    entry2.getValue().get(0)));
log.warn("JdbcTemplate took: {} ms", stopWatch5.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

// Most beautiful: NamedJDBCTemplate
Stopwatch stopWatch3 = Stopwatch.createStarted();
Map<String, Object> paramMap = createNamedParameterMap(domain, dimensionMap);
Set<Long> rs3 = extractIdSet(getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().queryForRowSet(sql, paramMap));
log.warn("NamedParameterJdbcTemplate took: {} ms", stopWatch3.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
}
```

Here are the results. The exact timings varied from run to run but always stayed in the same order of magnitude.

1. Using a query *without any* bind parameters finishes very quickly, in the order of *less than 100 ms*.
2. Using a Spring’s `JdbcTemplate` with 9 bind variables, the performance degrades to a crawl, with *about 4 seconds*.
3. Finally, using a `NamedJdbcTemplate`, which is easiest and most flexible, is just as slow as case 2; this at least, comes as no surprise since behind the curtains `NamedJdbcTemplate` will replace my query with named parameters into something equivalent to case 2.

It’s not getting the connections, as they all get them from the same connection pool. It doesn’t seem to be the `queryForRowSet()` function alone, since that’s actually what gets used in the fastest case as well. In the same vein, it doesn’t look as if had anything to do with Spring’s exception translation or participation in ongoing transactions, since that should affect case 1 as well.

So finally, the question: Why is Spring’s `JdbcTemplate` with bind parameters so very slow in this case compared to a plain statement without bind parameters?

Comment: Your gist link results in a 404. Post the code **in the question itselff**.

Comment: The code is _long_. Do you really want it in the question? Anyway, I fixed the broken link, sorry about that.

Comment: Yes, it should be in the question. That's the rule here. We want your question and its answers to still be understandable in 2 years, when your gist doesn't exist anymore, or has been modified.

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges. You are testing plain query execution with query execution and mapping the full result. To make a fair comparison, do the same and compare the same, don't compare half of the work done with all the work done.

Comment: You’re right, an unfortunate oversight. Getting all the results, or simply changing the code to extract `count(*)`, leads to all variants with bind paramenters to be equally slow. Edited the question accordingly; now it’s down to “Why are bind parameters slow”, which is something I still don’t quite understand (What kind of optimizer is that, anyway?) but which is not new.

Comment: That change isn't apparent in your question as that still has the old code and still a `queryForRowSet` does a whole lot more then just a simple execution. Create a fair testcase and can you put it on github? Really make sure you are comparing apples and applies and not apples and bananas.

Comment: No, the old code is not there anymore, and all three variant perform exactly the same `queryForRowSet()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that it is neither `JdbcTemplate` nor `NamedJdbcTemplate`. It also not about `PreparedStatement` versus `Statement`, even if the latter was the fastest. That was only because a normal statement does not come with bind parameters. If I have the query without bind parameters, it’s about the same speed with raw JDBC and `NamedJdbcTemplate` alike.

Our Oracle 11*g* simply choses a bad execution plan for this query with 9 bind parameters and sticks to it no matter what the actual parameters. I have no idea why and no real DBA is available.

A test on a PostgreSQL 9.3 database with the same data showed that it was equally fast both with and without bind parameters; with an out-of-the-box Ubuntu installation.

Comment: I know it's an old question, but did you found a workaround? I'm having a similar problem with Oracle 12c and 19c. Maybe there is some way to give Oracle a hint, which execution plan to use?

Comment: I haven’t looked into it thoroughly since then. In theory, Adaptive Cursor Sharing should alleviate this and bind variable peeking as well, but they were both introduced _before_ 12c. So – be careful in what you bind may still be the best advice.

Comment: I had a similar issue, but only with `String` parameters. Query for numeric parameters like `Long id` was fast.
String fields in my oracle DB are defined as `VARCHAR`. My datasource configuration has parameter `defaultNChar=true`, so each input String parameter was treated as `NVARCHAR` type, and Oracle DB had to perform a conversion under the hood for each String value, so index did not work.
Here is a workaround, when using prepared statement:

((OraclePreparedStatement)ps).setFormOfUse(columnIndex, FORM_CHAR);

https://stackoverflow.com/q/26296220/2377807